# How to modify target property of Event object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm executing async code, so I wanted to trigger an event once I finished. I created Event object, and I want to pass my current "this" object as a target property of the event. However, this property do not change.

```
var e = new Event("success");
e.target = myTargetObject;
console.log(e.target); // return 'null' for any myTargetObject.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var chngEvt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
chngEvt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true);
e.target.dispatchEvent(chngEvt);
```

Comment: You need to either add feature detection for support for `createEvent` and `dispatchEvent`, or warn the OP that not all browsers support those methods. Also useful to link to the [current W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-DocumentEvent-createEvent) and to an appropriate [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent). And the last line should probably be `this.dispatchEvent(…)`

Comment: Guys, thanks for your answers. My target object does not implement dispatchEvent, because it is not DOM element, it is just custom object. Any tips of how to start with?

Comment: Hi David, the event framework is specific and reserved to the appropriate dom object. There's even an event constructor depending on the object category. If you wish to raise events from custom objects you will have to build your own custom framework. rgds.